# rasterize xy to raster using southwest corner

Tags: r, raster, terra

```
  library(terra)
  
  dat <- structure(list(lon = c(73.0754166666667, 73.0754166666667, 73.0754166666667, 
                                73.0754166666667, 73.07625, 73.07625, 73.0770833333333, 
                                73.0770833333333, 73.0770833333333, 73.0770833333333), 
                  lat = c(-0.590416666666666, -0.587916666666666, -0.587083333333332, -0.58625, 
                          -0.592083333333333, -0.589583333333333, -0.593749999999999, 
                          -0.592083333333333, -0.589583333333333, -0.588749999999999), 
                  value = c(0.03, 0.02, 0.06, 0.032, 0.043, 0.023, 0.0123, 0.051, 0.0441, 0.015)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have a dataframe called dat which contains lon and lat and some value asspciated with it. However, the lon and lat
represent the southwest corner rather than the centroid of each row.

What I want to do is to create an a raster and populate it with the the values in `dat`. In order to do this, I need to create an empty raster first whose parameters are defined as.

```
  pixelsize <- 0.0008333333
  nr <- 6000
  nc <- 6000
  west_bound <- 70 # west_bound  and southbound represents southwest corner of the empty raster
  south_bound <- -5 

  # Calculate the extent of the raster
  east_bound <- west_bound + ncols * resolution
  north_bound <- south_bound + nrows * resolution
  
  blank_canvas <-
    rast(nrows = nr, #create a blank raster
         ncols = nc, 
         xmin = west_bound, 
         xmax = east_bound, 
         ymin = south_bound, 
         ymax = north_bound, 
         crs = 'epsg:4326',
         resolution = pixelsize)
  
  values(blank_canvas) <- -999
  
  dat_pts <- terra::vect(dat, geom = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 'epsg:4326') # convert to points
  r <- terra::rasterize(x = dat_pts, y = blank_canvas, field = "value", touches = T)
```

However, the resulting araster is treating each point in `dat` as the centroid instead of the southwest corner of an individual cell

```
    r_poly <- as.polygons(r)
    plot(r_poly)
    plot(dat_pts, add = T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the raster and points match, then clearly the coordinates refer to the center of the cells. Perhaps you did not define the raster appropriately?

Of course, you can move the points around if you believe that is justified.

```
library(terra)
d <- data.frame(lon = c(73.0754166666667, 73.0754166666667, 73.0754166666667, 
                     73.0754166666667, 73.07625, 73.07625, 73.0770833333333, 
                     73.0770833333333, 73.0770833333333, 73.0770833333333), 
                lat = c(-0.590416666666666, -0.587916666666666, -0.587083333333332, -0.58625, 
                     -0.592083333333333, -0.589583333333333, -0.593749999999999, 
                     -0.592083333333333, -0.589583333333333, -0.588749999999999), 
                value = c(0.03, 0.02, 0.06, 0.032, 0.043, 0.023, 0.0123, 0.051, 0.0441, 0.015))
        
x <- rast(ncols=6000, nrows=6000, xmin=70, xmax=75, ymin=-5, ymax=0, crs='EPSG:4326')

r <- res(x)
d$lon <- d$lon + r[1]/2
d$lat <- d$lat + r[2]/2

xd <- rasterize(d[,1:2], x, d[,3])
```